# How to show json array value in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am trying to pass the array value into jqgrid. As follows, the "ranking" value is another array, I would like to put each element (rank and score) in the array in a separate column:

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){        
        jQuery("#ggp_info").jqGrid('GridUnload');
        jQuery("#ggp_info").jqGrid({
            data: jsonObj.entry, 
            datatype: "local",
            colModel:[
                {name:'id',index:'id', width:55, align:"center"},
                {name:'name',index:'name', width:110, align:"center"},
                {name:'sort',index:'sort', width:50, align:"center"},
                {name:'ranking.rank',index:'ranking.rank', jsonmap:'ranking.rank', width:250, align:"center"}
            ],  
            rowNum:7,
            sortname: 'id',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            height: "100%",
            shrinkToFit: false,
            caption:"Leaderboard"
        }); 
    });
```

The jsonObj value is as follows:

```
{"entry":
[{"id":"10000935","name":"Queen","sort":"0","ranking":[{"rank":"1","score":"60"}]},
 {"id":"10000936","name":"Level1","sort":"0","ranking":[{"rank":"1","score":"700"}]}]
```

Comment: So i was stuck in the same problem, i thought jqgrid doesn't support sub objects, So i had this employee.Name and employee.Id id my grid. that didn't work for me. I ended up creating dto of my emplyoee and send the data employeeName and employeeId to grid explicitly, In your case can't you create a dto of ranking and send rankingRrank and rankingScore with your other data. I know this approach, may be oleg knows how to bind sub objects to grid. well if you want code for this approach, I can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to parse your json object and split it to retrieve separated rank and score
Then you have to create two columns like the following:

```
{name:'rank',index:'rank', editoptions:{value:rankArray}}
{name:'scores',index:'scores', editoptions:{value:scoresArray}}
```

So you will put ranks in rankArray and scores in scoresArray